# Add word content controls using open XML by appending to main document part XML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have loaded the `MainDocumentPart` into `XmlDocument` object like below

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wdPackage = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileNameWithPath, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart oMainDocPart = wdPackage.MainDocumentPart;

    oMainDocPartGlobal = oMainDocPart;

    // You must manage namespaces to perform XML XPath queries.
    NameTable nt = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    nsManager.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

    if (!(oMainDocPart == null))
    {
        //XmlNode rootNode = null;

        XmlDocument oMainDoc = new XmlDocument(nt);
        oMainDoc.Load(oMainDocPart.GetStream(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        mainDocument = oMainDoc;
        mainDocumentElement = oMainDoc.DocumentElement;
        mainNamespaceMrg = nsManager;

        //save doc
        oMainDoc.Save(oMainDocPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));
    }
}
```

Now how do i add content controls to this `XmlDocument` object. I can not create a `SdtBlock` object and append to the document body,instead i have to work with this `XmlDocument` object and append `SdtBlock` object so that content controls appear in the document.

Comment: Why do you need to use `XmlDocument` instead of the OpenXml classes?

Comment: Because i am working on an existing application which uses xPath queries to read from this XmlDocument object and replaces the existing content control text.Now i have a requirement of adding content controls and append them to the replaced content controls. If i use OpenXml classes i will have to rewrite the whole code.